# Change level in Cesium imageryProvider faster

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a cesium viewer using a local imageryProvider. I have 8 levels    available, but when I zoom in, Cesium takes longer than it   should to    call the next level. I zoom in, my map gets blurred, then  it changes    the level.

This is my viewer code:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer(mapID, {                             
    imageryProvider: new Cesium.UrlTemplateImageryProvider({
        url: '../../app/CesiumUnminified/Assets/Textures/myTiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        maximumLevel: 8
    })
});
```

Is there any way to call the next level faster so my map doesn't get blurred?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The next level is blurred while waiting for a response from your server.  In this case it looks like you're serving the images locally, so the server could be a development or stripped-down server that might not have the performance of a production server.

Most browsers these days have a "Developer tools" type section with a network tab, that shows traffic between the client and server.  For example, here's an article explaining [how to interpret this display in Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing#diagnosing_network_issues), although similar tools exist in Firefox, IE, and Edge.  Take a look at the timing of tile responses, and see if there's anything that can be done to the server to speed things up.